# For x in range only works 5 times

Tags: python

I'm working on a school assignment and I ran into a problem. When I input the amount of times I want the lottery row to be drawn, the program only does it up to five times. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
import random
from time import sleep
rivi = []
seen = set(rivi)
voittorivi = [7, 9, 10, 25, 31, 39, 40]

while True:
  try:
    rvnro = input('kuinka monta riviä pelataan?: ')
    rvnro1 = int(rvnro)
    print('pelataan', rvnro, 'riviä')
    break
  except ValueError:
    print('käytäthän vain numeroita.')
print(' ')
for x in range (rvnro1):
  while len(rivi) < 7:
    
    numero = random.randint(1,40)
    if numero not in seen:
      seen.add(numero)
      rivi.append(numero)
    else:
      u=0
  rivi.sort()
  if rivi == voittorivi:
    print('Voitit pääpalkinnon! Onneksi olkoon!')
  print(rivi)
  print(' ')
  sleep(0.1)
  rivi.clear()
```

Comment: are you aware that `range(6) gives an iterator over [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: You never reset `seen` so after 5 rounds of 7 numbers between 1 to 40 you have no more numbers to feel another row of 7...

Comment: @Tomerikoo good explanation of the issue!

Comment: also take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample as a way to generate 7 random numbers without the loop and set

Comment: @Tomerikoo that must be it. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer for a more detailed explanation and simplified solution

Answer (score 2):

```
  sleep(0.1)
  rivi.clear() # reinitiating the list
  seen.clear() # reinitiating the set
```

***The fix***

It will also help you end the algorithm, because it was stuck in endless loop since `while len(rivi)<7` was never achieved.

***Minor fix***

`.clear()`
was added on the new edit, as suggested by the comment.

Comment: IMO using `list.clear()` and `set.clear()` is nicer then creating new list and set objects and assigning them over the original ones

Comment: @Adam.Er8 will fix it

Comment: @Tomerikoo will do!

Comment: @Adam.Er8: Why? If you have some need to preserve an aliasing association, sure. Otherwise, it's perfectly fine to just make new ones (often cheaper, at least for `list`s, where `= []` avoids function call overhead). `rivi = []` is perfectly fine; `seen = set()` is... meh (I'm annoyed there is no real empty `set` literal, the one-eyed monkey operation, `{*()}` is... meh).

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right, there's even no reason they're defined outside the loop and then cleared at the end of every iteration, usually you'd just have an empty initialization once, at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `seen` so after 5 rounds of 7 numbers between 1 to 40 you have no more numbers to fill another row of 7. At the sixth round, after 5 numbers you covered all 40 options and have no more numbers for the remaining 2. So you get stuck in the `while len(rivi) < 7:` loop (because `rivi` will never get to 7 elements).

You can simplify this by using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) instead of calling `random.randint` in a loop and checking if the number was chosen already:

```py
numbers = list(range(1, 41))
for x in range (rvnro1):
    rivi = sorted(random.sample(numbers, 7))
    if rivi == voittorivi:
        print('Voitit pääpalkinnon! Onneksi olkoon!')
    print(rivi)
    print(' ')
    sleep(0.1)
```